# Prisma Mongodb id length issue in Next.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, next.js, prisma

I am using using Prisma with mongodb in Next.js 14 and I am getting an id length error.

This is my generateId function for the id generation.

```
export const generateId = () => {
  const timestamp = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000).toString(16).padStart(8, '0');
  
  const randomPart = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[x]/g, function () {
    return ((Math.random() * 16) | 0).toString(16);
  }).toLowerCase();

  return timestamp + randomPart;
};
```

Sample id it returns.
65c3521ea6f7915eed0b6c03
**I am getting this error**
message: `Malformed ObjectID: provided hex string representation must be exactly 12 bytes, instead got: "undefined", length 9 for the field 'userId'.`

This is how I am assigning the id.

```
const newActivity = await prisma.activity.create({
              data: {
              id: generateId(),
              campaignId: updatedCampaign.id,
              workspaceId: workSpaceId,
              createdAt: new Date(),
              userId: userId,
              type: ActivityConstants.TRIGGER,
            },
```